# Add parameter at onClose in relation Modal

Tags: react-hooks, react-tsx

Goal:
When you press the button named "yes 1", the value should contain "yes yes" and in the end the console.log should display "test yes yes".

When you press the button named "yes 2", the value should contain "no no" and in the end the console.log should display "test no no".

The display of the value "test yes yes" or "test no no" take place at index.tsx.
The execution or the decision take place at ModalForm.tsx.

Problem:
In technical perspectiv, tried to find a solution by using this code  onClick={props.onClose("yes yes")} but it doesn't work.

How do I solve this case?

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-rpltpq

Thank you!

---

index.html

```
<div id="root"></div>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

---

index.tsx

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import { ModalForm } from './ModalForm';

import './style.css';

interface dddd {
  clientid: string | undefined;
  idid: number;
}

const getTest = () => {
  console.log('test');
};

const App = () => {
  const [clientiddd, setClientid] = useState('ddfdf');
  const [idid, setIdid] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        data-bs-toggle="modal"
        data-bs-target="#myModalll"
        className={'btn btn-outline-dark'}
      >
        {'data'}
      </button>
      <br />
      <ModalForm clientid={clientiddd} onClose={getTest} />
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

---

ModalForm.tsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

interface ModalProps {
  clientid: string | undefined;
  onClose: () => void;
}

export const ModalForm = (props: ModalProps) => {
  return (
    <div
      className="modal"
      id="myModalll"
      data-bs-backdrop="static"
      data-bs-keyboard="false"
      tabIndex={-1}
      aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel"
      aria-hidden="true"
    >
      <div className="modal-dialog">
        <div className="modal-content">
          <div className="modal-header">
            <h4 className="modal-title">T</h4>
            <button
              type="button"
              className="btn-close btn-close-black"
              data-bs-dismiss="modal"
              onClick={props.onClose}
            ></button>
          </div>

          <div className="modal-body">
            TITLE:
            <br />
            <button
              type="button"
              data-bs-dismiss="modal"
              onClick={props.onClose}
            >
              yes 1
            </button>
            <button
              type="button"
              data-bs-dismiss="modal"
              onClick={props.onClose}
            >
              yes 2
            </button>
            <br />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-nw6upt?file=index.html

---

index.html

```
<div id="root"></div>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

---

index.tsx

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';
import { ModalForm } from './ModalForm';

interface dddd {
  clientid: string | undefined;
  idid: number;
}

const getTest = (result: string) => {
  console.log('testff ' + result);
};

const App = () => {
  const [clientiddd, setClientid] = useState('ddfdf');
  const [idid, setIdid] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        data-bs-toggle="modal"
        data-bs-target="#myModalll"
        className={'btn btn-outline-dark'}
      >
        {'data'}
      </button>
      <br />
      <ModalForm clientid={clientiddd} onClose={getTest} />
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

---

ModalForm.tsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

interface ModalProps {
  clientid: string | undefined;
  onClose: (result: string) => void;
}

export const ModalForm = (props: ModalProps) => {
  return (
    <div
      className="modal"
      id="myModalll"
      data-bs-backdrop="static"
      data-bs-keyboard="false"
      tabIndex={-1}
      aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel"
      aria-hidden="true"
    >
      <div className="modal-dialog">
        <div className="modal-content">
          <div className="modal-header">
            <h4 className="modal-title">T</h4>
            <button
              type="button"
              className="btn-close btn-close-black"
              data-bs-dismiss="modal"
              onClick={() => props.onClose('ccc')}
            ></button>
          </div>

          <div className="modal-body">
            TITLE:
            <br />
            <button
              type="button"
              data-bs-dismiss="modal"
              onClick={() => props.onClose('aaa')}
            >
              yes 1
            </button>
            <button
              type="button"
              data-bs-dismiss="modal"
              onClick={() => props.onClose('bbb')}
            >
              yes 2
            </button>
            <br />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's somewhat hard to understand your question, but let me try.

```
onClick={props.onClose('yes yes')}
```

What this code does is that it calls `props.onClick` with `yes yes` as an argument and assigns the returned value as the onClick listener.

Assume the `props.onClose` is this:

```
function onClose() {
  console.log('test')
}
```

What it does here is that it calls this function (it logs `test` to the console) but since this function is not returning anything, it passes `undefined` as the `onClick` here.

If instead your function was this:

```
function onClose(result) {
  return function () {
    console.log('test', result)
  }
}
```

Now it would call `props.onClose` with `yes yes` and it would return a function. This anonymous function would be passed as the `onClick` event listener and when you click, it would call that so there would be `test yes yes` logged only after clicking.

You can as well do it differently, keep your `onClose` function as it was but introduce `result`:

```
function onClose(result) {
  console.log('test', result)
}
```

but now you have to pass this function instead of calling it:

```
onClick={() => props.onClose('yes yes')}
```

As you can see, there will always be *one anonymous function* somewhere in there, it's just a question of where that function is and what is called when. Hope this explanation helps.

Comment: Is it possbile that you can use Stackblitz (https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-rpltpq) and apply your code?

Or paste the whole code for index.tsx and ModalForm.tsx in this answer page?

It is easier to understand.

Comment: Well, the point of Stack Overflow is to provide help and teach people which is why we post answers here and not to someone else's git/editor. But, if you have any follow up questions, I am happy to guide you through it!